# How to embed a php graph in a web-page

Tags: php

I am using this script which is one of the examples provided by the graph itself. When I put this on a web-page by itself, it's drawing the graph. But when I embed the code in an already existing web-page (with some content), it doesn't draw a graph.

I did the experiment using img src and its working fine.
But I just wanted to submit some parameter along with that graph in same web page.
How do I do that one without using "img src"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you not want to use `<img>`?

Comment: already i used img src in my code.actually the problem is i want to submit some values along with the graph then only that need to be appear in the web page.

Comment: Okay, but why does `<img>` not work for that purpose? Can you show some code?

Comment: img src is working fine in my code but i just want to copy the total graph code in my exist php script.when i copied the total graph code in exist php script it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i just want to copy the total graph code in my exist php script

Better don't. It's best to just use an `<img>` element to embed the graph. Use GET parameters to pass values:

```
<img src="script.php?param1=123456&param2=124050">
```

Creating inline images is theoretically possible using [`data:` URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), but it's not fully supported by Internet Explorer yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by generating new [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) or by using [javascript](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/image/preload.html).

Comment: ya we can use javascript but i am using mysql column values for generating graph.

Comment: You should be able to do so using javascript on the mysql column. Also, there's nothing wrong with `<img src`, also, you can use inline CSS.

Comment: No worries. On this forum press the tick symbol beside the question which is correct to mark it as the answer.